# Can't switch to Discrete GPU Hybrid Graphics ATI/intel

Tags: 14.04, kernel, hybrid-graphics, xrandr, vgaswitcheroo

Just recently I had got my hybrid graphics working with DRI_PRIME=1. I obviously have the open source drivers. Now for some reason that I can't figure out it has stopped working.

*xrandr --listproviders*

Only shows my Intel card now as before it showed my radeon twice.

*cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch*

Shows this:

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

I know DynOff means that the driver has turned it off automaticly and is a feature for my kernal 3.13.7(I upgraded it to 3.15.2 to try and fix the issue). The question I have is, how do I turn it back on?

Extra Info: DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo |grep renderer Shows:

```
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile
```

GPU: ATI Radeon HD6700/ Intel HD3000

Thanks,
Aaron